# What is"be + to + noun""?

Tags: prepositions, auxiliary-verbs

here is my example
"my back is to the world" it's from the song enemy from imagine dragon

what does that sentence mean ? and what is the grammar rules behind that sentence ?
Is "to" necessary?

Comment: Have you looked up the word **to** in a dictionary? (Hint: in your sentence it is being used as a preposition.)

Comment: "Is" used in your sentence as an auxiliary verb which describes something. "To" means toward, heading in your sentence. So, this sentence describes something which is towarding somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the preposition "to" is necessary. In this case, it means "toward" or "in the direction of", and the sentence means that the singer's back is positioned toward the world. In other words, he is facing away from the world, and his back is directed toward it.

I would construe the prepositional phrase "to the world" as a predicate adjective, describing "my back".

Comment: Predicative, but a PP, not an AdjP.